# The error about "Function “and” is not a unary operator"

Tags: sql, dolphindb

why is the following query showing error?：

```py
Function “and” is not a unary operator
```

I do the query like this"

```py
select  
  a as code
from    data 
where   instrumentkind != 'Future'
  and instrumentkind != 'Combo' 
  and instrumentkind != 'VolatilityTrade'
context by instrument_code csort time limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by line breaks, you can change the scripts to the following:

```py
select a as code
from    data 
where   instrumentkind != 'Future' and instrumentkind != 'Combo' and instrumentkind != 'VolatilityTrade'
context by instrument_code csort time limit 1
```